# Using stuff in dynamic query string sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to fetch two columns with comma separated.This code

```
SELECT STUFF(( SELECT ',' + Cast(Column1 As varchar(50))+'_'+Cast(Column2 As varchar(50)) FROM Table FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', NVARCHAR(MAX)), 1, 1, '') As Result
```

works for me.But i need to use it in a dynamic query string its getting error when i am trying to do this.

```
Declare @String AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
Set @string='SELECT STUFF(( SELECT ',' + Cast(Column1 As varchar(50))+'_'+Cast(Column2 As varchar(50)) FROM Table FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', NVARCHAR(MAX)), 1, 1, '') As Result'
EXEC sp_executesql @String
```

Comment: Tag the dbms used, some non-ANSI SQL there.

Comment: you are having some issues with the `'` inside the query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the quotes in dynamic SQL by doubling them up, otherwise SQL Server thinks the quote has ended:

```
Set @string='SELECT STUFF(( SELECT '','' + Cast(Column1 As varchar(50))+''_''...
```

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/17/sql-server-how-to-escape-single-quotes-fix-error-105-unclosed-quotation-mark-after-the-character-string/